# Sed replacing pattern starts with but not contains string

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I have the following text file: **file.text**

```
Cygwin
value: c
Unix-keep
value: u
Linux
value: l
Unix-16
value: u
Solaris
value: s
Unix-replace-1
value: u
Unix-replace-2
value: u
```

I want to replace all lines values based on previous string : starting with **Unix-** but excluding containing string **keep**

So in the end affected lines sould be the ones after:
Unix-replace-1 and Unix-replace-2 with value **value: NEW_VERSION**

Expected output:

```
Cygwin
value: c
Unix-keep
value: u
Linux
value: l
Unix-16
value: NEW_VERSION
Solaris
value: s
Unix-replace-1
value: NEW_VERSION
Unix-replace-2
value: NEW_VERSION
```

I tried following sed script:

```
sed '/^Unix-/ {n;s/.*/value: NEW_VERSION/}' file.text
```

but this can only get starting but not excluding -keep substrings. I am not sure how to combine the excluded ones.

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't parse XML nor HTML with regex

Comment: Ignore the xml format and let's say we have text files and we only need to replace the line after Cygwin, Unix-keep, Solaris etc.


Cygwin
version:c
Unix-keep
version:u
Unix-replace-1
version:u

etc

Comment: You are on a professional QA web site, we don't encourage people to do plain wrong things with wrong tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk -v new='NEW_VERSION' 'f{$0=$1 FS new} {f=(/^Unix-/ && !/keep/)} 1' file
Cygwin
value: c
Unix-keep
value: u
Linux
value: l
Unix-16
value: NEW_VERSION
Solaris
value: s
Unix-replace-1
value: NEW_VERSION
Unix-replace-2
value: NEW_VERSION
```

Comment: It is possible that I may have some lines that have Unix as starting characters but not containing -replace- substring.

e.g. Unix-1, Unix-2 etc

Comment: Sure, it's only software so anything's possible. If the example you provided in your question doesn't represent your real data well enough then fix your example to include the cases where the answer I posted won't work plus anything else (e.g. rainy-day/edge cases) you may have left out.

Comment: I fixed my input.
The logic is to recognize only lines that start with Unix- but do not contain keep substring. 
Unix-replace-1 , Unix-16, Unix----- ( next line without keep substring ) should only be replaceable

Comment: Thanks. Just a small observation:
If I want to have more dynamic the replacement line what would be the solution?
e.g. valueUnix: NEW_VERSION

Answer (score 1):

Using a proper [xml](/questions/tagged/xml) parser (**the question was originally plain XML before edited by OP**):

The XML edited to be valid (closing tags missing) :

```
<project>
    <Cygwin>
        <version>c</version>
    </Cygwin>
    <Unix-keep>
        <version>u</version>
    </Unix-keep>
    <Linux>
        <version>l</version>
    </Linux>
    <Solaris>
        <version>s</version>
    </Solaris>
    <Unix-replace-1>
        <version>u</version>
    </Unix-replace-1>
    <AIX>
        <version>a</version>
    </AIX>
    <Unix-replace-2>
        <version>u</version>
    </Unix-replace-2>
</project>
```

The command:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '//project/*
    [starts-with(name(), "Unix") and not(starts-with(name(), "Unix-keep"))]
    /version
' -v 'NEW_VERSION' file
```

To edit the file *in place*, use

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u ...
```